# What type is returned by function that using assert statement?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function like this:

```py
def foo(a, b):
    assert a == b, "a isn't equal to b"
```

And I'd like to add type annotations to do mypy checking and all that.

```
>>> bar1 = foo(3, 3)
>>> bar2 = foo(3, 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
AssertionError: a isn't equal to b
>>> type(bar1)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> type(bar2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bar2' is not defined. Did you mean: 'bar1'?
```

OK, in case when expression is true, this function returns `NoneType` object. But what type is returned in case when expression is false? How I can to correctly specify the type to do checking?